# How do I temporarily suspend mail delivery to a specific domain (non-local) with Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

Using Postfix and custom transports I can manage delivery speeds depending on the recipient's domain. (For example, I send max one message per second to *@hotmail.com)

I also use similar rules to block bad destinations (htmail.com is blocked right away, avoiding many loops in the queue).

However, I'd like to temporarily suspend mail delivery to a destination for 24 or 48 hours (mails to *@gmail.com suspended, everything else delivered). Messages would queue up during this time, and would be delivered only when I want by changing the config.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put messages in a HOLD state

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    ...
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/hold
```

/etc/postfix/hold:

```
gmail.com        HOLD
blah.com         HOLD
```

Make sure you run `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/hold` whenever you update the file.

If you want to release all messages on hold, use [postsuper](http://www.postfix.org/postsuper.1.html):

```
# postsuper -H ALL
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work after all. Mail is immediately submitted. Maybe because I send mail from $mynetworks ? REJECT and DISCARD don't work either, I had to go with transport's error:

Comment: Ok, my bad, mail sent locally with mailx is not checked because it's not sent to smtpd.
Works very well :)

Comment: If you want to temporarily hold all outgoing email you can use a `static` type instead: `check_recipient_access static:HOLD`. An `inline` type might also be useful to hold a few domains without the need for a `hash`. http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types

Comment: Note: if you're forcing clients to send email via submission you might have different submission rules written at `master.cf` and your email still might get delivered. Check what's being applied to your submission and add the `check_recipient_access` to the appropriate places, in my case it was `smtpd_mua_relay_restrictions`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a [**transport map**](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html):

`gmail.com defer:`

Answer (score 0):

To put on hold for specific domain:

```
postqueue -p | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } { if ($7 == "your@domain.com" ) print $1 }' | tr -d '!*' | postsuper -h -
```

To release for a specific domain:

```
postqueue -p | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } { if ($7 == "your@domain.com" ) print $1 }' | tr -d '!*' | postsuper -H -
```

Comment: Just no. The $7 will match the Sender Email address on the same line as the queue ID. The recipient email address is on the next line, and it needs a domain match, not email match.